# Bot Framework Composer Custom Runtime Start Command

Tags: azure-functions, bot-framework-composer

I've got a bot that uses a custom runtime so I can implement a custom action using azurefunctions.

The bot publishes to the Azure Function resource and works great in live practice.

However, I'm struggling to get the bot up and running in the BFC "Local bot runtime manager" to test in the Emulator without having to publish every time.

The error I come across  whilst starting the bot in BFC is "Start bot failed - Specify which project file to use because azurefunctions contains more than one project file."

What is the correct syntax to specify a .csproj file?  My "Start Command" currently looks like "dotnet run --project azurefunctions".  By default there are 2 .csproj files in the runtime\azurefunctions directory 1. Microsoft.BotFramework.Composer.Functions and 2. Microsoft.BotFramework.Composer.FunctionTemplate

Comment: I haven't  found any docs to describe bot framework composer custom start command, but as you said you used 2 .csproj, so I think [this way](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/run-multiple-asp-net-core-projects-using-dotnet-run-command/) may deserve to try.

Comment: The start command is based on the dotnet syntax as it's a dotnet run command.  But I'm unfamiliar and can't quite get the syntax right.  I need the syntax to specify which .csproj file the BFC will use.